# CSS - How do you hide first div when hovering over second div (and vice versa)?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to hide the first `div` child when hovering over the second `div` child and vice versa,  while keeping them in the same position on the page. However CSS's general sibling combinator `~` is limited in this scenario. So far, I have the following:

```css
.container div:nth-child(1):hover~div:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
}

.container div:nth-child(2):hover~div:nth-child(1) {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box-container">
    Box 1
  </div>
  <div class="box-container">
    Box 2
  </div>
</div>
```

The second style doesn't work (as expected). I have been trying to figure out a solution but I am not sure how to proceed. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The second style doesn't work that way because CSS does not go backwards. If you want, you can create a duplicate 3rd element or use JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the hover on the parent container to hide the child divs and then show the hovered div:

```css
.container:hover div {
  opacity: 0;
}

.container div:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box-container">
    Box 1
  </div>
  <div class="box-container">
    Box 2
  </div>
</div>
```